# Copy file from one directory to another using cmd in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to copy a file from one directory to another and do something with that file. I need to copy it with `cmd`, rather than `File.Copy()`, because I need the copy to be done as a part of `ProcessStartInfo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code and change `startInfo.Arguments`, but `/C` should be!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C copy example.txt backup.txt";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, `/C` definitely helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bat-file to copy one or multiple files (using *). Then execute the batch file.

```
        string batFileName = @"C:\{filePath}\copy.bat";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(batFileName, @"copy {fileName}.{extension} {destination-filePath}");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to formulate this answer using the DOS Copy syntax along with this Stack Overflow QA
[Start cmd window and run commands inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616010/start-command-windows-and-run-commands-inside)

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

var process = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"copy c:\Source\Original.ext D:\Dest\Copy.ext");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
process.WaitForExit();
```